# Controller is being executed twice for single request

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-4

i have a `button` and calling a function on its `click` event. but respective controller-method is being executed twice on single click.

**`code`**

```
<input type="button" value="View Details" class="btn" id="happyNow" onclick="fun()"/>
<script>
    function fun() {
        alert('clicked!');
        window.location = '../Surah_CRUD/Test';
    }
</script>
```

**`controller method:`**

```
public class Surah_CRUDController : Controller
    {
      public ActionResult Test()
      { 
             ...
         return View();
      }
   }
```

alert in `script` hits only once but if i put some `breakpoint` in controller, it is executed twice. how to fix it???

Comment: You might want to edit your button id......

Comment: i even changed classname as well but still no difference @SpaceBison

Comment: When debugging, what does your call stack say for each of the calls?

Comment: i don't know how to check call-stack @NicklasWinger

Comment: @NicklasWinger now???

Comment: When breakpoint is hit, show your call stack. Can't remember how to activate it. Google :) (on my cell right now)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The button submits the form it is in. You don't have a separate controller action that receives the submitted model so the same action is being hit. The  method on click also requests the controller action.

Comment: how to fix it then ? :(

Comment: You can subscribe to the submit event and cancel it, or you can remove the window.location modification from the script handler. Btw try canceling the click (return false) that should also work.

Answer (score 0):

it worked with following code:

```
<input type="button" value="View Details" id="meree" onclick=" return fun()" />
<script>
function fun() {
            var request = $.ajax({
            url: '../Surah_CRUD/fuck',//action method url which defined in controller
            type: 'get',
            cache: false,
            data:'',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
        }); 
        return false;
    }
</script>
```